# How to conver getLocalizedMessage() to Custom Exception Object - MismatchedInputException

Tags: spring, exception, servlets, objectmapper

When I send restTemplate.postForEntity i would like to catch exception

```
public DriverDTO create(CreateDriverForm createDriverForm) throws JsonProcessingException {
    try {
        ...
        ResponseEntity<DriverDTO> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/drivers", entity, DriverDTO.class);
        return responseEntity.getBody();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException exception) {
        ExceptionResponseObject object = objectMapper.readValue(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), ExceptionResponseObject.class);
       
    }
}
```

and convert exception.getLocalizedMessage() to my custom exception response object from Rest Api:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionResponseObject {
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String errorName;
    private String message;
}
```

But I am getting the error below:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of 
`com.example.ekrany.responses.ExceptionResponseObject` (although at least one Creator exists): 
no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (400)
 at [Source: (String)"400 : "{"timestamp":"2022-08-02T12:00:13.3734961","status":400,
"errorName":"MethodArgumentNotValidException","message":"[Email already exists]"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

How should I convert it? Or maybe is there any better practice to handle 4xx status from api when I post any form and getting error?

EDIT:
I have changed method to expectecing ResponseEntity with String

```
public DriverDTO create(CreateDriverForm createDriverForm) throws JsonProcessingException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        DriverRequestModel driverRequestModel = new DriverRequestModel(createDriverForm.getName(), createDriverForm.getSurname(), createDriverForm.getEmail());

        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(driverRequestModel, httpHeaders);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/drivers", entity, String.class);

    if (responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){
        return objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), DriverDTO.class);
    }
    else{
        ExceptionResponseObject object = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), ExceptionResponseObject.class);
    }
}
```

and now I am getting:
"org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest:
400 : "{"timestamp":"2022-08 02T13:24:14.9394083", "status":400, "errorName":"MethodArgumentNotValidException", "message":"[Email already exists]"}""

Answer (score 1):

because if its error it cant convert to DriverDTO.
try some like this

```
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
                restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/drivers", entity, String.class);
if (responseEntity.statusCode == 200){
objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), DriverDTO.class);
}
else{
ExceptionResponseObject object = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), ExceptionResponseObject.class);
}
```

Comment: I tried to change it but still I am getting error about "jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.ekrany.responses.ExceptionResponseObject` "

Comment: i edit the answer .ExceptionResponseObject object = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), ExceptionResponseObject.class);

Comment: I updated my Edit, after change I am getting HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest in line with postForEntity